# How to create a generic struct?

Tags: go, generics

How can I construct a generic struct?

I tried:

```golang
type SafeSet[type T] struct {
    Values map[T]bool
}
```

---

I want to be able to do e.g.

```golang
SafeSet{ Values: make(map[net.Conn]bool) }
SafeSet{ Values: make(map[string]  bool) }
SafeSet{ Values: make(map[int]     bool) }
```

Comment: Right now, with Go 1.17 and older you *can't*. Try next year, when generics are added to Go 1.18.

Comment: @mkopriva What do you propose one does instead? Duplicate e.g. the `SafeSet` for each type?

Comment: `type SafeSet map[interface{}]interface{} ;  x := make(SafeSet)`?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen yes, that is what I would do if it was what I needed to have. There are analogous examples in the standard library, like the `NullXxx` types in `database/sql`.

Comment: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the current Go version, 1.17. Unfortunately there's nothing else to say.

---

After generics will be added to the language, probably in Go 1.18 (early 2022), the syntax for such a parametrized types, according to the current accepted proposal, will be:

```
type SafeSet[T comparable] struct {
    Values map[T]bool
}
```

In particular:

- The [type constraint](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#constraints) comes after the type name `T`
- If you want to use `T` as a map key, you must use the built-in constraint `comparable`, because map keys must be comparable — i.e. support `==` operator.

Then you have to [instantiate](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#generic-types) the parametrized type with an actual type argument:

Example:

> To use a generic type, you must supply type arguments. This is called instantiation. The type arguments appear in square brackets, as usual. When we instantiate a type by supplying type arguments for the type parameters, we produce a type in which each use of a type parameter in the type definition is replaced by the corresponding type argument.

```
    s0 := SafeSet[net.Conn]{Values: make(map[net.Conn]bool)}
    s1 := SafeSet[string]{Values: make(map[string]bool)}
    s2 := SafeSet[int]{Values: make(map[int]bool)}
```

Since instantiating `SafeSet` literals looks kinda verbose, you can use a generic constructor func:

```
func NewSafeSet[T comparable]() SafeSet[T] {
    return SafeSet[T]{Values: make(map[T]bool)}
}
```

The syntax is, obviously, the same, except that in this case you are explicitly instantiating the function with the type arg:

```
    s3 := NewSafeSet[uint64]()
    s3.Values[200] = true
```

Gotip Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/Qyd6zTLdkRn